# UTF-8 special chars output

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters

When I output something (from my utf-8 db) like

```
this "text" is nice
```

the html code show

```
this &quot;text&quot; is nice
```

How to show exactly the apostrophe `"` with php?

Thanks

Comment: What are you using to print this text? Type the used PHP code here for us.

Comment: show the php line you are using to print

Comment: if neither answer worked for you please add some code.

Comment: i'm using the twig template engine to print, so {{ object.title }}

Answer (score 0):

Using the function [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
echo htmlentities('this "text" is nice');
```

Answer (score 0):

use [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

From the PHP manual:

```
<?php
 $orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";
 $a = htmlentities($orig);
 $b = html_entity_decode($a);
 echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now
 echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
?>
```